# Find a plane of $R^3$ that doesn't contains any of the coordinate vectors.

Tags: vector-spaces

By giving a basis, describe a two-dimensional subspace of $R^3$ that contains none of the coordinate vectors $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$.

Seems not to exist. For all choices of planes (through origin) always will be some free coordinate who them could spawn its coordinate vector.

There is a solution?

Comment: The plane orthogonal to $(1,1,1)$ certainly contains none of the three vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the plane spanned by $(1,1,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try $U  =\operatorname{span}((1,0,1),(0,1,1))$ ? *Try Thinking Geometrically*